# Can I use extractor for local html files

Tags: import.io

I'm using this article [here](http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/4830902-open-local-files) to load a local html file.  I can use extractor to get the data, but I can't publish the API.  I'd like to run the API extractor on multiple pages.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to run the API across multiple pages on a local server.

However if you pushed those files to be hosted online instead of locally, then you should be able to train an extractor to the hosted pages and subsequently publish the API.

Here are some [free web hosts](http://www.webhostingbest10.com/free-web-hosting) you could try.

If you are familiar with AWS could also use [s3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)